# ASP.NET Core MVC and 2 Web API projects

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

There are a web app and two web api services + two projects in one solution. In the production server there are two web applications: one web and one service. In the service application I found the two web api service and I do not understand why and how can I build, or deploy these to api into onr web application.
I am new in the Core business so please help.

Comment: To build `dotnet build`. To deploy, start with `dotnet publish`. This is not a site for tutorials, so get your hands wet and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could create a new web application on the production server to hosted the web api project or create nested two web application in the service web sites in the web server.

After doing this , you will have three web application on the production server.

One Core MVC application and two web api application.

Then you could post these three application to each IIS web application. Notice: You need to modify the MVC web api's url since there are not the same.

More details about how to build and publish the web application to the server, you could refer to below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio